# Hölders inequality doubt exercise

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image]*

How can $\int_x|f|^{p_2})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\mathbb{1}_X d\mu\leqslant(\int_x|f|^{p_2})d\mu)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}(\int_X|\mathbb{1}_X|^\beta)^{\frac{1}{\beta}}$ be the application of Hölders inequality if $p_2$ is not the inverse of $\frac{1}{\alpha}$?

*Hölder equality is:$\int_X |f\times g|\leqslant(\int_X |f|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\int_X|g|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can stick any exponent you'd like on $1_X$ without changing its value, because $1_X$ takes only the values $0$ and $1$. Does this solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've inserted the extra step:

$$\int_X (\lvert f\rvert^{p_2})^{1/\alpha}\mathbf{1}_X\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq \left(\int_X \left((\lvert f\rvert^{p_2})^{1/\alpha}\right)^{\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/\alpha}\left(\int_X \lvert \mathbf{1}_X\rvert^{\beta}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/\beta} = \left(\int_X \lvert f\rvert^{p_2}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/\alpha}\left(\int_X \lvert \mathbf{1}_X\rvert^{\beta}\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{1/\beta}$$

Essentially, the $1/\alpha$ is cancelling out with the $\alpha$ in the first integrand.